# Gentle reminder to the person who haven't reply my email at all

Tags: technique

I'd like to know what expression I can use for the gentle (but strong) reminder to the person who has bad manners to ignore emails.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kind of questions we handle here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would deal with this by email:

> [Name],
>
> I'm sorry to hassle you, but this is now urgent. [Optional: explain briefly but firmly why it's urgent.]
>
> Will you please let me know when I can expect a reply to the message below?
>
> Thanks,
>
> Andrew

Some other things to bear in mind:

- If you suspect this person is ignoring their inbox, why send more emails? You need another route. Can you call them instead?
- If you believe they're only ignoring *your* emails, that's different, but in my experience you will still be more likely to change that if you can find a way to telephone them.
- Nobody ever does anything because of 'bad manners'. Especially if this is a workplace email, it's more likely that they have been too busy, or they've been forced to prioritise something else.
- You may or may not think that's excusable, but if you want them to help you, don't adopt an accusatory tone. Put yourself in their position: whatever the circumstances, through their eyes, they've been doing their best.

Hope that helps.